# Entity escaping occurs on Network-Wide Rep Graph

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-graph, stackexchange.com

[image: Global Reputation graph pop-over box]

LEGO® is indeed the only site to my knowledge that uses a special character in its site title. The only similar site would be SF&F, but the title is "Science Fiction and Fantasy", so no ampersand problem occurs.

Comment: Because of this bug, we've decided we're closing shop - no more network. Sorry guys, VxJasonxV RUINED IT FOR EVERYONE :)

Comment: I don't get it. (No really, I have no idea how to go about understanding the meaning behind that joke.)

Comment: VxJasonxV, I think @Nick is using hyperbole to create humor by implying that StackExchange, Inc. is rage-quitting based on this one bug report.  You are the straw that broke tha camel's back =)  (I could be wrong though, my grasp on humor in general is pretty tenuous)

Comment: (Did I kill the joke by questioning it? Probably.) Nothing to see here besides a bug report. You may now resume your normal Stack Exchange commenting trends. Move along now.

Comment: @VxJasonxV [This](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DontExplainTheJoke) might come in handy.

Comment: I feel so enlightened. (But I'm not going to delete my comments.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wooops, good catch. Fixed now. ([Example](https://stackexchange.com/users/153865/joubarc?tab=reputation))